# Updating one entity via another updating

Tags: entity-framework

Say you have an entity that models an invoice and another entity modelling the invoice items. How would you up date a sum of the total value of all items on the invoice as the invoice items are added and amended?

Comment: Update them where? In memory? On a page? You're making a calculation, why would you be updating a total?

Comment: In general is bad practice to keep updating totals and saving them in the database, you can make add `[NotMapped]` to your `Total` property and just create a `GetTotal` method that returns the invoice total whenever the property is accessed.

Comment: My theory in having this column was to allow me to perform more efficient request to the db. Surely there is value in that?

Answer (score 0):

Although I would agree with the comments advising against storing calculated fields in a database, if you wanted to you could use interceptors to intercept any changes to the invoice items and from there re-calculate the invoice.

There is a good example of implementing interceptors here: http://iextendable.com/2010/10/20/implementing-ef4-change-interceptors/

It is based on EF4 but does work for EF5.

There is a NuGet packages which contains the interceptor code called Isg.EntityFramework which is again on the above site

Using the latest version of that NuGet packages the code would look something like:

```
public class RecalculateInvoiceTotalInterceptor : Isg.EntityFramework.Interceptors.TypeInterceptor
{
    public RecalculateInvoiceTotalInterceptor(Type targetType)
        : base(targetType)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnBefore(DbEntityEntry item, System.Data.EntityState state, InterceptionContext context)
    {
        base.OnBefore(item, state, context);

        // Code here to update invoice
    }

}
```

You would also need to register the interceptor:

```
InterceptorProvider.SetInterceptorProvider(new DefaultInterceptorProvider(new AuditInterceptor()));
```

There is a similar OnAfter method you could also use but then the recalculation would be outside of the InvoiceItem transaction. You can gain access to the DbContext via the InterceptionContext passed in to the OnBefore method

Comment: Interesting to know that interceptors are available but seems like an overly complex way of solving it when, like you say, I should just calculate this field rather than storing it in the long term. Thanks for the advice